# Why are my videos loading slowly from google drive?

Tags: html, google-drive-api, video-streaming, html5-video

We have a website that serves some training videos. Most of them are HD.
Instead of serving them from our server directly, I thought it would be a good idea to upload these videos to one of our company's google drive accounts, and just have our website tell browsers to load the video from google. After all, Google servers, and their upload speed, is way way faster than ours.

When you upload a video to Google Drive, to have direct access to it (which is what the html `<video>` tag needs), you need to use the google api. Our `<video>` tag ends up looking something like this:

```
<video ... src="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/OUR_FILE?key=OUR_KEY&alt=media">
```

where `OUR_KEY` identifies our client to google, and `OUR_FILE` identifies the file we want to link to.

This works, but often, it's slow to buffer the video, which is surprising, as Google is obviously rarely slow.

Are we hitting some kind of quota? How do we find which quota we are hitting? Is there a way to increase this? Or was google drive simply not designed for this?

We are doing this on a fairly small scale - at best, we have one viewer a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google drive was not designed for this, and google will give no guarantee or warranty for this usage pattern. They may even consider it abuse.

> We are doing this on a fairly small scale - at best, we have one viewer a week.

Using proper AWS or GCS would cost very little for this use case.